Getting VS-code Haskell "Go to definition" working on Ubuntu 24.04
On Ubuntu 24.04 I am not able to get the Haskell extension "Go to definition" functionality to work in VS code.
It always says no definition found even when the definition is in the same file.
I already tried:
Uninstalling VS code and removing the directories $HOME/.config/Code and ~/.vscode and reinstalling it with
wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo install -D -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64,arm64,armhf signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
sudo apt update

sudo apt install code
I tried disabling the extensions and re-enabling them. I tried opening the root folder of the project with "open folder" I tried saving a workspace. I tried adding fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 to /etc/sysctl.conf. I tried creating yet a new empty workspace and starting over again.
I looked for the "c_cpp_properties.json" property in ~/.config/Code/User/settings.json and it was not there.
In other words I tried everything proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37341849/vscode-go-to-definition-not-working.
How do I fix this? How do I go about debugging this?
P.S.: Everything was working perfectly on Ubuntu 20.04

The first thing you might do is verify with the maker that the extension works with Ubuntu 24.04
